# How to display colored emojis in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, emoji

Is there any way to display colored emojis in tkinter?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pyperclip

root = Tk()

def copy():
    pyperclip.copy(button['text'])
    print("Copied!")

button = Button(root , text = "" , font = "arial 70" , command = copy)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

When I run this code, I get something like this:

[image]

Here, the emoji shown in the button is completely black and it is not colored.

I know I could have used an image of the emoji in my button, but it won't be possible if I have to do the same thing for hundreds of emojis.

What I want is to make the emoji colored so that it will be easier for people to recognize it.

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Which Python and tkinter version are you trying this with?

Comment: @J.M.Arnold: I am using Python version: 3.9.1 and tkinter version: 8.6

Comment: Try this: `label.config(fg="light green")`. If you want the inside of the emoji to be coloured, then I don't think you can use a `<tkinter.Label>`. By the way you can use a `<tkinter.Canvas>` and place images there.

Comment: @TheLizzard : By `making the emoji colored`, I mean that the emoji should have it's original colors(``) instead of just having a black drawing when it is displayed on the window.

Comment: For that I don't think you can use a `<tkinter.Label>`. If you use a canvas, you can place hundreds of pictures but it will be hard to implement.

Comment: @TheLizzard : Being able to achieve this with any widget is ok. All I want is to display the emoji with it's original colors without using any image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pip install pywin32, 
pip install pillow
```

and

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import win32clipboard

def emoji_img(size, text):
    font = ImageFont.truetype("seguiemj.ttf", size=int(round(size*72/96, 0))) 
    # pixels = points * 96 / 72 : 96 is windowsDPI
    im = Image.new("RGBA", (size, size), (255, 255, 255, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.text((size/2, size/2), text, embedded_color=True, font=font, anchor="mm")
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

def copy():
    emoji_data = button['text']
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT, emoji_data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    print("Copied!", emoji_data)

root = tk.Tk()
text=""
emoji = emoji_img(80, text)
button = tk.Button(root, image=emoji, text=text, command=copy)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible (to me) to show coloured emojis in Tkinter whether using ttk or tk. So for showing coloured emoji in Tkinter, I have an idea. First I have downloaded a picture of the emoji from google. Image link: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/79/c2/71/79c2714528ebf4669603e32121ae6019.png

Then save the image in the same directory where your code is saved.

At last you have to use this image in a label. Here is the code of how I have used this image:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

account_bitmap = PhotoImage(file = "emoji.png") 
account_bitmap = account_bitmap.subsample(3, 3)

label = ttk.Label(root , image= account_bitmap, compound= TOP)
label.pack()

mainloop()
```

Here is my output:
[image: My Output]

I think it is your desired output.

Comment: Well what if we need 100 emojis and text in between those emojis? I don't think tkinter can handle that many widgets.

Comment: @TheLizzard : Yes, that is what I am also thinking. If I want to do this for hundreds of emojis, I wont be able to download the images of all of them. I am looking for a way where I don't need to use any image.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think the way emojis look (and their colour) depends on the font. If you don't want to use images, you might need to find a better font.

Comment: @TheLizzard To show text, pass an extra parameter "text" to show text. To change text position, change the compound to your desired direction. And to show 100 emojis, you should use a loop. And about the font, yes obviously there may any font that may support showing coloured emojis.

Comment: @SabilIslam : Can you suggest me a font that can support showing colored emojis? I have tried different fonts but I could not find any font that can show colored emojis.

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use images is that it will become way harder to copy the emoji to my clipboard. Please see the edited code in my question for more details. If there is an easy way to copy an emoji to my clipboard, I am completely fine with using images.

Comment: @Lenovo360 It's not a fact that you have to copy images. You can simply change the command so that it copies the character  whenever you click on it!

Comment: Yes, but how can I know what character to copy? If I have many images, it will be way harder to identify what is the emoji and what character to copy.

Answer (score 0):

I modified @kimhyunju answer for my own purposes. This is the easiest solution to my problem of trying to integrate full color emojis into my tkinter app. Originally I wanted full color emoji's in button text but it doesn't seem possible. I have altered the solution a bit and added transparency. I also use customtkinter it returns a CTkImage instead of a PhotoImage.

```
from customtkinter import CTkButton as Btn, CTkImage, CTk
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont


def emoji(emoji, size=32):
    # convert emoji to CTkImage
    font = ImageFont.truetype("seguiemj.ttf", size=int(size/1.5))
    img = Image.new("RGBA", (size, size), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text((size/2, size/2), emoji,
              embedded_color=True, font=font, anchor="mm")
    img = CTkImage(img, size=(size, size))
    return img


app = CTk()

btn = Btn(app, text=None, fg_color="transparent", image=emoji(""))
btn.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to show colorful emojis in Tkinter title.

```
root.title('')
```

Beyond title, I was able to represent colorful emojis from string.
Only when running the code in [Create.withcode.uk](https://create.withcode.uk) an online Python editor.